# svn upgrade - not working when execute command from subdirectory

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

When I tried to upgrade my working copy on my linux server - I am getting the error

```
 Can't upgrade '/var/www/vhosts/xx.xx.xx.xx/abc/xx/yy/zz/Command' as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy root, the root is '/var/www/vhosts/xx.xx.xx.xx/abc'
```

Do I need to upgrade from root itself?

I am not sure if I upgrade it from root, my updated and modified files will be safe?

Note - I am using `svn upgrade` command.

Comment: The command pretty much explicitly TELLS you that you need to do this from root. Why didn't you believe what it said?

Comment: I do believe but I just want to know - is it safe or not if I upgrade it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your working copy must be upgraded at the root of the working copy. Otherwise, the WC would be left in a very inconsistent state. Consider how a client would be expected to attempt to deal with a WC that consists of mixed format changes.

I recommend that people commit all changes prior to upgrading to to be safe, but you will *probably* be OK to upgrade from where you are now. If it hoses the WC, check out a new one & copy your changes over.

Comment: yeah many people are working on same file so it is now difficult to figure out which file - none of my svn update command is working, so I have to upgrade it now. And i hope my changes won't affect because of this.

Comment: Wait. Why are "many people working on same file?" Working copies should be **one per user**. If you don't have a separate WC for each user, you negate many of the benefits of using version control in the first place.

Comment: No I mean to say many people are using `svn update` and then `svn commit` command and some people uses svn version 1.7 and some uses 1.6 on their local web server - I don't know what causes this issue as i have SVN 1.7 on my server, so hope this will resolve my issue :) .. will do it tomorrow and will let you know ;)

Comment: Clients are all independent. What you do to your working copy will not impact anyone else's.

Comment: Update => do changes => commit :)

Comment: But upgrading *your* WC has no effect on other WCs, that's my point.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to confirm that will it do any harm if i update file next time from the repository  ..you are right - it won't :)